# Group hash sum of files

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a console program which should display groups of duplicates files.
I have a method that returns a collection of full paths to the files:

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetFullPath(String fullPath)
{
    /*
     realisation
    */
    yield return new FileInfo(file).FullName;
}
```

I also have a method that returns the hash sum of file:

```
public String GetMd5HashOfFile(String file)
```

It all works correctly; I can display full paths to files and I can display file hashes, but how can I display groups of full paths to files with the same hashes?  Groups should be separated by empty line.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?  Have you looked at any of the LINQ operators to see if one might help you group items?  If you took the time to look for one, I imagine one would stand out as being a good choice to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var allFiles = getAllFiles(fullPath); // or whatever

return allFiles.GroupBy(c => GetMd5HashOfFile(c));
```

You can then use it however you want, for instance:

```
foreach (var v in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hash: {0}", v.Key);

    foreach (var f in v)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", f);
    }
}
```